# Veeam Linux Agent failed backup on Ubuntu 16.04, No objects to backup error

Tags: linux, backup

When I start job I get this:

```
  15:11:13        [warn] Backup is missing in repository
  15:11:14        [error] Failed to perform backup
  15:11:14        [error] No objects to backup
  15:11:14        [error] Processing finished with errors at 2017-09-09 15:11:14 CEST
```

I think this is because Veeam see main hdd as only disk **sdb**, not with partitions like other hdds like **sda** and **sdc**.

[image]

I want to make volume backup, whole **sdb** to **sda** disk. Configuration passed ok but when I start job I get error.

This is `lsblk -a` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 596.2G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0 596.2G  0 part /mnt/storage
sdb      8:16   0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0  93.1G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
├─sdb5   8:21   0 195.6G  0 part /home
└─sdb6   8:22   0   9.4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   0 596.2G  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0 596.2G  0 part /mnt/storage2
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
loop0    7:0    0         0 loop
loop1    7:1    0         0 loop
loop2    7:2    0         0 loop
loop3    7:3    0         0 loop
loop4    7:4    0         0 loop
loop5    7:5    0         0 loop
loop6    7:6    0         0 loop
loop7    7:7    0         0 loop
```